# Do creatures put on the battlefield via a sorcery have summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a card named [Doubling Chant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220152), the effect of this card is "For each creature you control, Search your library for a creature with the same name and put it onto the battlefield. Then Shuffle your library".

After this phase can I then attack with the creatures gained this way or do they suffer from summoning sickness?

My guess is that If they do not have haste they suffer but doubling them seems to suggest a mirroring of the original creature at the time... Its a vague mechanic in all honesty

Comment: _"but doubling them seems to suggest a mirroring of the original creature at the time"_. You can't depend on the flavor of a card to determine how it works mechanically. The cards put onto the battlefield aren't "doubles" of the original creatures in any meaningful sense. If the card was called "Cousins With a Strong Family Resemblance Chant", it would still work the same way ;-)

Comment: @Autar I saw that question but it wasn't anything to do with Summoning sickness as a mechanic it was more what the card read itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Summoning sickness applies to all creatures without haste, regardless of how they came to be. From the comprehensive rules:

> 302.6. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature can’t attack unless it has been under its controller’s control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the “summoning sickness” rule.

"Summoning sickness" is not a characteristic of the card. It cannot be copied or added. Haste allows creatures to ignore the rule, but if they somehow lose haste, then the rule will apply once again.

A creature does not *have* summoning sickness; a creature *is affected by* the summoning sickness rule. The former is just an easier concept for players to latch on to, and it works most of the time.

The Judge's Corner (on YouTube) has [a video on Summoning Sickness](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asYHxwoElIM) that explains the ins and outs of summoning sickness in greater detail. Both new and veteran players will get something out of it.

Comment: Haste is medicine that merely suppresses the symptoms :)

Comment: Can you lose haste? I guess you can lose "all abilities"

Comment: @corsiKa Losing all abilities works, but it is possible to lose only haste. Equip [Swiftfoot Boots](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220261) to Elvish Mystic. It has haste. Equip Swiftboot Boots to something else. Elvish Mystic loses haste.

Comment: Ah yes, equipment would definitely do it, and in the same vein so would auras.